# What is the value of $i+i^2+i^3+\cdots+i^{23}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Can anyone help me with this question and show me a step by step solution please?

> The imaginary number is $i$ is defined such that  $i^2=-1$. What is $i+i^2+i^3+\cdots+i^{23}$?

Comment: To get multi-character exponents, enclose them in braces, so use i^{23} to get $i^{23}$  The same thing works throughout $\LaTeX$, whatever is in braces acts like one character.

Comment: Work $\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the values of $i^0,\, i, \,i^2, \,i^3,\,i^4,\,$...$,\,i\,^5,...$: you'll see a *cyclic* pattern emerge.

**Observations:**

- $i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4\;\; = \;\;i + -1 + - i + 1 \;\;=\;\; 0$
- For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $i^n = i,\, i^2,\, i^3,\, i^0 = i^4$.
- That is, for any given $n,\,$  consider $\;k\; = \;n\pmod 4.\;$ Then $i^n = i^k$

Comment: I understand the pattern now. Thank you made it simple.

Comment: Great! You're welcome, Little Jon!

Answer (score 12):

Just use the geometric series :

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n-1} {r^{k} = \frac{1-r^n}{{1 - r}}}$$

Set $r= i , n=24$ and remember to take away 1 ( your summation starts from k=1 , the above formula starts from k=0).

Comment: This works, but requires dividing complex numbers.  Given the question, that may not be available.

Comment: @RossMillikan : fair enough! but I like to throw in the math equivalent of monkey wrench into the works! Make them ask "why we can't use this?"

Comment: @RossMillikan: Actually, it doesn't really require dividing by complex numbers...

Comment: @trb456:  the denominator is $1-i$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Right, but the numerator is...

Answer (score 11):

Hint:  do you know what $i^2, i^3,$ and $i^4$ are?  That should lead you to expect a pattern.

Comment: what does i to the power of 1 equal?

Comment: Little Jon: $i^1 = i$, just as $2^1 = 2$, and $i^0 = 1$, just like $2^0 = 1.$

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** Since $i^2=-1$, we have $\color{#C00000}{i}+\color{#00A000}{i^2}+\color{#C00000}{i^3}+\color{#00A000}{i^4}=0$.

Comment: Also note that $i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4 = i^5 + i^6 + i^7 + i^8 = \cdots$

Comment: @Novice: we even have $i^{n+1}+i^{n+2}+i^{n+3}+i^{n+4}=i^n(i^1+i^2+i^3+i^4)=i^n\cdot0$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $  Call it $\,S.\,$ $\, (1\!-\!i)(1\!+\!S) = (1\!-i)(1\!+i\!+\cdots\! + i^{23}) = 1\!-i^{24} = 1\!-(-1)^{12}\! = 0\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,S = -1.$

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication of complex numbers is, geometrically, rotation.

The angle between the positive real number line and a given complex number is called the *argument* of that number, usually given in radians. When two complex numbers are multipled together, the product's argument is the sum of the arguments of the two factors.

The Euclidean distance of a complex number from $0$ is its modulus. When two complex numbers are multiplied together, the modulus of the product is the product of the two moduli.

Because the argument of $i$ is $90$ degrees ($\pi$ radians), and its modulus is $1$, when we multiply a number by $i$, we rotate that number by 90 degrees.

So $i$ is the unit vector pointing straight up. Then $i\times i = i^2$ is a vector pointing straight left ($-1$), $i^3$ is a vector pointing down ($-i$), and $i^4$ is a unit vector pointing right ($1$). If we add these together, we get zero because they all cancel out.

The subsequent powers just keep going around the unit circle in the same pattern: $90, 180, 270, 0, 90$ ...  or $i, -1, -i, 1, i, ...$.

You have $23$ powers being added.  The first $20$ are just five groups of four which each cancel to zero individually, and so add to zero overall. You're left with three powers which must continue around the circle like this: $i, -1, -i$. The sum of these is $-1$, since $i$ cancels $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$i\cdot \frac{i^{23}-1}{i-1}=\frac{i}{i-1} \cdot (i^{23}-1)=\frac{i(i+1)}{-2} \cdot (-i-1)=\frac{i(i+1)^2}{2}=\frac{i(1+2i-1)}{2}=-1.$$